# docker VS 2017 - Not able to start container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, docker-compose

I am new to docker.  I have VS 2017 community edition installed on my machine.

I have installed

- Docker for windows
- Docker tools for windows.

I created a new ASP Dot net core 2.0 Web API project with 'Enable Docker Support' option enabled.

I was able to build default project but when I start debugging it gave me below error.  I can see new image is created using 'docker image list -a' command but VS is unable to start container.

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Building webapplication9
Creating dockercompose4820272847090409016_webapplication9_1 ... 
[1A[2K
Creating dockercompose4820272847090409016_webapplication9_1 ... [31merror[0m
[1B
ERROR: for dockercompose4820272847090409016_webapplication9_1  Cannot start service webapplication9: container be38d8f606526b8957cbce69c30a9cc329ee79e53f6b216e66d0cdc5895f4a14 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {"CommandLine":"powershell -Command [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep([System.Threading.Timeout]::Infinite)","User":"ContainerUser","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\app","Environment":{"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":"Development","ASPNETCORE_PKG_VERSION":"2.0.3","ASPNETCORE_URLS":"http://+:80","DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER":"1","NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES":"c:\\.nuget\\fallbackpackages","NUGET_PACKAGES":"C:\\.nuget\\packages"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
ERROR: for webapplication9  Cannot start service webapplication9: container be38d8f606526b8957cbce69c30a9cc329ee79e53f6b216e66d0cdc5895f4a14 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {"CommandLine":"powershell -Command [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep([System.Threading.Timeout]::Infinite)","User":"ContainerUser","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\app","Environment":{"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":"Development","ASPNETCORE_PKG_VERSION":"2.0.3","ASPNETCORE_URLS":"http://+:80","DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER":"1","NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES":"c:\\.nuget\\fallbackpackages","NUGET_PACKAGES":"C:\\.nuget\\packages"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
Encountered errors while bringing up the project..

For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting    docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets 346
```

Am I missing any pre-requisite ?

Comment: did you config Docker on Windws? Share drives?

Comment: How do you start your container? from Visual Studio?

Comment: @IgorCova I am using 'Windows container' and I don't think we have 'Share drive'option for the windows container.  When we start debugging in VS 2017 it automatically starts container.

Comment: @IgorCova it seems to be some issue with VS 2017 when using windows container.  I created brand new dot net core project with Linux container and I was able to launch is successfully....

Comment: Maybe, sometimes the container isn't launched from the first time

Comment: for some reason, its happening for me every time if I am using 'Windows container', all good with linux containers.

Comment: check it https://twitter.com/Igor_Cova/status/1011955504833286144